# App bundle language split doesn't seem to handle regions

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I have the following error message when uploading the bundle of my app on the play store :
[image]

The most heavy part of the APK is the raw folder, it contains a lot of .mp3 files.
All files are localized in raw folder, like this :
[image]

Inside build.gradle, I have configured like this :

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = true
    }
    density {
        enableSplit = true
    }
    abi {
        enableSplit = true
    }
}
```

Each language has the exact same number of .mp3 files, yet when I generate the apks from the .aab with bundletool, I can clearly see that the **zh** apk is heavier than other languages :
[image]
[image]

It seems there is only 1 apk for both **zh-rCN** and **zh-rTW** resources.
So, what should I do to handle the language split properly, with the regions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only splitting by language is supported. Splitting by region is not supported. You can file a feature request.